# Make Django return response as a "different filename"

Tags: django, http, filenames, httpresponse

I have a Django view which returns an `HttpResponse` with a special MIME type to make the user's browser "download" the file instead of view it in the browser.  The problem is that the default filename that the response will be saved as is the URL which the user tried to access.

Is there any way to include a default filename in the `HttpResponse` object or do I have to redirect to a different URL to make this happen?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a relevant example in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
    return response
```

Comment: Minor note: you need quotes around the filename or browsers will use "download.bin".  That is: filename="somefilename.pdf"

Comment: Got an error trying to use mimetype, but changing the HttpResponse to
HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf') worked for me