# HttpResponse Django does not change file name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I had followed 3 of answers:

[Generating file to download with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django)
[Make Django return response as a "different filename"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833536/make-django-return-response-as-a-different-filename)
[Adding a variable in Content disposition response file name-python/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380788/adding-a-variable-in-content-disposition-response-file-name-python-django)

My `POSTMAN` is v4.10.3

```
class SBrandJobRawDataView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = {
            "message": _("GET method is not allowed"),
        }
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        from_date = request.data.get('from_date')
        to_date = request.data.get('to_date')
        queryset = get_raw_sbrand_record(from_date, to_date)
        filename = f"From_{from_date.get('year')}-{from_date.get('month')}-{from_date.get('day')}_to_" \
                   f"{to_date.get('year')}-{to_date.get('month')}-{to_date.get('day')}.xlsx"
        # Allow only last file stay in the server.
        clean_dir("xlsx")

        # Create Excel report
        gen_sbrand_report(queryset, filename)

        # Open file
        abs_file = os.getcwd() + '/' + filename
        xls_file = open(abs_file, 'rb')

        # Response with attachment
        response = HttpResponse(xls_file,
                            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename={filename}"
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return response
```

I am aware that I am mixing `Django` and `Django REST` response. If I use `from rest_framework.response import Response` I get error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/sbrand-jobs/reports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 103, in render
    separators=separators
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/siam-sbrand/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 54, in default
    return obj.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 15: invalid start byte
"POST /api/sbrand-jobs/reports HTTP/1.1" 500 103626
```

This is `debugging line`

```
(Pdb) response['Content-Disposition']
'attachment; filename=From_2017-1-1_to_2017-12-25.xlsx'
```

**Problem:**
I got `response.xlsx` not my assigned name.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
from django.utils.http import urlquote
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(urlquote(filename))
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I could not remember my solution to this. But I will update to you when I am free.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: @joe, check it out