# Django output csv file, filename is not setting as the value of Content-Disposition

Tags: django

I want to download a csv file with custom filename in a django project, but somehow the downloaded filename just display as "download.csv" instead of using the value of filename in Content-Disposition. I also tried to print `csv_response['Content-Disposition']` out, but I'm getting a very strange string `=?utf-8?b?YXR0YWNobWVudDsgZmlsZW5hbWU9Iuivvueoi+aKpeWQjeaDheWGtV8yMDE5MTEyODA3NDI0Ny5jc3Yi?=`

the code snippet is :

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
def download(self, request):
    registrations = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    csv_response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    csv_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_custom_name_{time}.csv"'.format(
        time=time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.localtime())
    )

    writer = csv.writer(csv_response)
    writer.writerow([
        some content,
    ])

    for registration in registrations:
        term_title = '{order} th'.format(order=registration.term.order)
        course_title = registration.course.title

        writer.writerow([
            registration.user.email,
            course_title,
            term_title,
            str(registration.confirmation_code),
            str(registration.payment_due),
            str(registration.payment_paid),
            str(registration.source),
            str(registration.created_at),
            str(registration.updated_at),
            str(registration.payment_source),
        ])

    return csv_response
```

the django I am using is 2.2

any ideas why this is happening? I am a newb.
Thx in advance

The response header in chrome Dev tools:
[image]

Comment: Did you check in your client (e.g. in chrome using [dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)) if all expected headers are set properly?

Comment: @mfrackowiak I found the Content-Disposition is not included in the response header after I download the file, but I do not understand why. The file is all right.

Comment: I think you don't need the quotes around the file name, I will suggest you remove that and try again... 'attachment; filename=some_custom_name_{time}.csv'

Comment: @prime_hit no, that's not the reason, I tried before. It is the encoding problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem, by following the answer in the below post:
[HttpResponse Django does not change file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025550/httpresponse-django-does-not-change-file-name)

I guess that it is that because the string of Content-Disposition needs to be encoded, and if no, then somehow cannot operate on that, by using `urlquote`, it is solved.
Explanation about `urlquote` is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/utils/http/)

UPDATE:
Also, a simpler way to resolve this without importing `urlquote` is to add `encode()`, like below:

```
csv_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_custom_name_{time}.csv"'.format(
            time=time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.localtime())
        ).encode()
```

Comment: did you try to use some normal string, like "Abc.csv"? can you check if passing a hard-coded value solves the issue.

Comment: @NalinDobhal if not using `urlquote`, then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
csv_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_custom_name_{}.csv"'.format(
            time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.localtime())
        )
```

Comment: I have tried this before I post, it is not working. And also I found the Content-Disposition is not included in the response header after I download the file.